# Can Vuforia AR button open another view or app?

Tags: iphone, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality

I'm making an app using unity and vuforia extension. When app will recognize an image it should show a button above it and, when the user presses it, I want to display a photo gallery. Is there a way to make this button trigger showing another UIView? Or show another app?

Comment: Do you know what method this button triggers? If you do, search more generically for "programatically opening uiview" or something like this.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can definitely do this. There are resources out there that will teach you how to create a plugin where you can launch an external UIView. For example: http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/56755-Unity-plugin-to-handle-loading-native-Cocoa-UI-s-with-ease

Also, you can open another app using Apple's URL scheme, described here: 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Introduction/Introduction.html